# Golang convert interface{} to array of N size

Tags: arrays, go, interface, type-assertion

I have an array of `T` wrapped in an interface. I know the size of the array beforehand. How do I write a generic function that gets back an array (or a slice) for any array length? E.g. for size 3 I want something like

```
var values interface{} = [3]byte{1, 2, 3}
var size = 3 // I know the size

var _ = values.([size]byte) // wrong, array bound must be a const expression
```

I can't really do a type switch because `[1]byte` is a different type from `[2]byte` etc so I'd have to explicitly enumerate all possible sizes.

Comment: You can't. As the error states, array size must be a constant expression; the size is a part of the array type definition, and Go is compile-time type-safe. If you need arrays of varying sizes, use slices instead.

Comment: Even if `size` could be a runtime value, what would you do with the result? You can't assign it to anything except a variable of type `interface{}`, and you're back where you started.

Comment: Fixed-sized arrays are rarely useful in Go. Are you sure you can't just use a slice here?

Comment: @EliBendersky @Adrian I could use a slice in the "receiver" type, but the original type as a fixed-sized array comes from a library that unmarshals some data and puts them in a `[]interface` (since originally they could be any type). What I need is to get hold of the values inside the `[]interface` type, but can I?

Comment: Can you point at the code that does the marshalling in the input library?

Comment: @EliBendersky here you go https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/accounts/abi/argument.go#L266

Comment: It doesn't seem like that code is marhaling Go array types, unless I'm misreading something

Comment: But it does, when I `printf(%T)` the return values of that function I definitely have arrays; that's why I posted the question in the first place :)

Comment: Seems to me that the code in the link you sent is returning a `[]interface{}` as a slice of undefined typed data, not a `interface{}` with an array as the code you originally posted.

Comment: @GustavoKawamoto it is used in places like https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/accounts/abi/argument.go#L106, putting the values in a map of type `map[string]interface{}`; sometimes that `interface` value is an array, hence my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflect is your friend here:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var in interface{} = [3]byte{1, 2, 3} // an element from your []interface{}
    var size = 3                          // you got this
    out := make([]byte, size)             // slice output

    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        idxval := reflect.ValueOf(in).Index(i) // magic here
        uidxval := uint8(idxval.Uint())        // you may mess around with the types here
        out[i] = uidxval                       // and dump in output
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", out)
}
```

Slices are the better choice output here, since you indicate that you have an undefined length.
What Magic here does is indexing the value of your input interface through reflect. This is not quick, but it does the trick.

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was looking for! Thank you :)